# Facebook Koala loop not working properly

Tags: facebook, koala

The following is the code that does not work -

```
for x in @y
  v = @graph.get_object("me") # This is not a useful code. I'm just trying to make a point
end
```

While the following code works

```
u = @graph.get_object("me")
for x in @y
  v = u
end
```

I'd appreciate help with this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried testing something similar to this in the console, and saying something like

```
for i in 1..1000
  @graph.get_object("me")
end
```

and after some amount of time, it finally finished.. but it took a while. I'm assuming there's a chance the connection between you and facebook can get blocked/closed/timeout.

Every call took about a second. I think the problem is that facebook's API has a bandwidth limit. So, in the case of your first block of code, you're calling get_object over and over, where as in the second one, you are simply calling the API once, then just assigning that value over and over.

Comment: Thanks @Robert That seems to be the problem. Do you know what the max bandwidth required by FB is and how I can determine whether I have enough time to do what I intend to do.

Comment: What exactly do you intend to do? I think the best/easiest solution is to figure out a way to not call facebook's API so many times at once.

Comment: Thanks @Robert! I'll see if I can do it using FQL instead.